# Story Identification - Post apocalyptic movie about male vs. female factions

Tags: story-identification

I saw a part of this movie on TV a few months ago, and I don't know its title.

Details:

- It was set in north america, after a nuculear holocaust.
- In it there were two warring factions, one made up of females and one made up of males.
- One of the scenes I remember is one of the males finding the United States presidential bunker in the middle of the desert they lived in.
- They say 'president' like 'Prezz - ee - dent'
- They get a hazmat suit out of the bunker and one puts it on, and they take some hand grenades from the bunker and make a show of force outside the women's faction camp.
- The name of it was something like "America 5000"

**What is the name of this movie?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're referring to the movie [America 3000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_3000). It's described by Wikipedia as...

> ...a 1986 post-apocalyptic science-fiction cult film which takes place
>   900 years in the future in Colorado. Mankind has been reduced to Stone
>   Age conditions and is under the rule of Amazon-like women warriors.
>   The film was directed by David Engelbach, and stars Chuck Wagner,
>   Laurene Landon, and William Wallace.

You can watch the whole thing here;

Comment: Yep thats it. I just had the numbers confused. Thanks a ton.